# How to use "distinguish" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I wrote a sentence as follows:

> Being able to do X distinguishes me between a programmer who works with code and a system engineer who is capable of designing a revolutionary system like Google and Facebook.

What I meant by the above sentence is "X makes a system engineer who is better than a programmer who does coding for a living".

Does my sentence convey the intended meaning? Is this a correct use of the word "distinguish"? Feel free to suggest any other alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP probably shouldn't use the word *distinguish* at all in this context. It's usually only used in constructions distinguishing A from B, or distinguishing A from "everything/everybody else". It doesn't really work with *three* different identities (*me, programmer,* and *engineer* here).

I would suggest...

Being able to do X identifies me as a systems engineer capable of designing a revolutionary system like Google or Facebook, not just a programmer who works with code.

Note that my suggestion is only concerned with grammaticality and fluency. I wouldn't advise any single individual to go about claiming they could design the equivalent of Google or Facebook. It's no slur on the technical skills of [Sergey Brin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Brin), [Larry Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Page), [Mark Zuckerberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg), et al, to say that these are now vastly complex systems, far beyond the ability of any single person to implement.

Answer (score 4):

I would be inclined to break it into two sentences:

> Being capable of doing X distinguishes me from a programmer who works solely with code.  This makes me a system engineer, capable of designing a revolutionary system such as Google or Facebook.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I can only pick one answer...

Comment: You can unpick the other answer though if you prefer this one.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is badly worded.  It would more properly be stated:

*Being able to do X distinguishes me, **as** a programmer who **writes** code, from a system engineer who is capable of designing a revolutionary system like Google **or** Facebook.*

It is still a convoluted sentence that could be stated more clearly.  It also overstates the (enormous) capabilities of the engineer, which negates your message ..

Answer (score 0):

"Being able to do X distinguishes me ***from*** a programmer who ***merely*** works with code, ***unlike*** a systems engineer who is capable of designing a revolutionary system like Google and Facebook." -That is what the OP means to say, I guess.

It may be still better if you say ***unlike a true*** systems engineer ...

Also, note that it's ***systems engineer*** with an added ***s***.